# Inverse grep does not find all matching lines

Tags: grep, words

**EDIT:** I am making this too complicated. It's not about inverse grep. I get the same results using just `grep -x -f stop.txt < in.txt`. If `who` comes before `whose` in the stop word file, the result is just `who`. When the order is reversed in the stop word file, both lines in `in.txt` are found. I have the feeling that I fundamentally do not get grep.

---

I cannot get inverse grep to work like I expect in order to remove lines containing a stop word from a file. The order in which the stop words are given affects the result.

Suppose I have two files. An input file `in.txt`:

```
who
whose
```

And a file with a list of stop words `stop.txt`:

```
who
whose
```

If I "filter" `in.txt` with an inverse grep search on the stop words in `stop.txt`, I get:

```
$ grep -vx -f stop.txt < in.txt
whose
$
```

Only if I change `stop.txt` to

```
whose
who
```

do I get:

```
$ grep -vx -f stop.txt < in.txt
$
```

I do not understand why the order of words in the file with stop words is of importance.

Comment: Since you are doing whole-line matches, are you sure there is no trailing whitespace or non printing character in either of the files? Check with `od` or `cat -A` for example

Comment: I can't really replicate this error with the native `grep` on FreeBSD, nor with GNU `grep`.  Are you sure there are no trailing spaces after `whose` in any of the files? What Unix are you on and what `grep` are you using?

Comment: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD on macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: I've thought about trailing whitespace. But does not seem to be the matter. As I said in my comment to Marcus's answer, replacing `who` and `whose` with `a` and `b` leads to the expected result. It looks like the behavior has to do with the fact that `who` is a substring of `whose`, no?

Answer (score 5):

With the pattern files

```
$ od -bc shortlong
0000000   167 150 157 012 167 150 157 163 145 012
           w   h   o  \n   w   h   o   s   e  \n
0000012
$ od -bc longshort
0000000   167 150 157 163 145 012 167 150 157 012
           w   h   o   s   e  \n   w   h   o  \n
0000012
```

we can test some of the variations, here with the macOS `grep`
(2.5.1-FreeBSD):

```
$ grep -x -f shortlong shortlong
who
$ grep -x -f shortlong longshort
who
$ grep -x -f longshort shortlong
who
whose
$ grep -x -f longshort longshort
whose
who
```

`who` when first hides the longer `whose` match. This appears to be
a bug.

The problem only appears when the expressions come from a `-f` file, not
when the equivalent (we hope) expression is given as an argument:

```
$ grep -x -E 'who|whose' shortlong
who
whose
$ grep -x -E 'who|whose' longshort
whose
who
$ grep -x -E 'whose|who' shortlong
who
whose
$ grep -x -E 'whose|who' longshort
whose
who
```

GNU `grep` (3.7) does not exhibit this problem (nor does the `grep` on
current versions of OpenBSD):

```
$ ggrep -x -f shortlong shortlong
who
whose
$ ggrep -x -f shortlong longshort
whose
who
$ ggrep -x -f longshort shortlong
who
whose
$ ggrep -x -f longshort longshort
whose
who
```

Therefore to avoid this bug do not use `grep` verion 2.5.1-FreeBSD, or
instead form the regular expressions into an argument from the file by
replacing non-ultimate `\n` with `|` for `grep -E`.

```
$ paste -s -d \| shortlong
who|whose
$ grep -x -E -- "$(paste -s -d \| shortlong)" shortlong
who
whose
```

### Concerning Alternation

Longer strings should ideally be listed before shorter strings in
regular expression alternations, [among other edge cases](https://github.com/mauke/Data-Munge/blob/master/lib/Data/Munge.pm#L192), which
means one should prefer the `longshort` file or `whose|who` forms.

`grep` appears (when it is not buggy) to get this right, but other
regular expression engines will stop on the first match, which must be
listed longest first if you want those to match:

```
$ printf 'who whoses the whosefolk' |
grep -o -E 'who|whose|whosefolk'
who
whose
whosefolk
$ printf 'who whoses the whosefolk' |
perl -nle 'print for /who|whose|whosefolk/g'
who
who
who
$ printf 'who whoses the whosefolk' |
perl -nle 'print for /whosefolk|whose|who/g'
who
whose
whosefolk
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I suspected it had to do with the fact that `who` is a substring of `whose` but I very much lack the technical expertise to confirm this as a possible bug.

Comment: strictly speaking, `\|` is not part of basic regexes, even if some support it. The `re_format` man page on my mac describes ERE first, and then says "Obsolete (''basic'') regular expressions differ in several respects.  '|' is an ordinary
     character and there is no equivalent for its functionality." but it also admits an extensions: "When the REG_ENHANCED flag is passed [...], additional features are activated. [...] For enhanced basic REs, '+', '?' and '|' remain regular characters, but '\+', '\?' and `\|' have the same special meaning as the unescaped characters do for extended REs"

Comment: I think reverse sorting (`sort -r`) the file with the patterns might work to ensure that no pattern is a prefix of a latter one if that's indeed enough to prevent the issue.